# Delegate inherited methods explanation

Tags: c#, delegates

Where methods BeginInvoke, Invoke, EndInvoke goes from?

I went to MulticastDelegate and Delegate, and they doesn't contain any methods declarations. Of course I understand that signature of this method depends on delegate declarations. But I can't understand how it works.

Here what [John Skeet says](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx) about it:

> Any delegate type you create has the members inherited from its parent
>   types, one constructor with parameters of object and IntPtr and three
>   extra methods: Invoke, BeginInvoke and EndInvoke. We'll come back to
>   the constructor in a minute. The methods can't be inherited from
>   anything, because the signatures vary according to the signature the
>   delegate is declared with. Using the sample code above, the first
>   delegate has the following methods

I'm not native English speaker and I'm a bit confused with fact that

> Any delegate type you create has the members inherited from its parent

but then

> The methods can't be inherited from
>   anything

Please explain how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the compiler processes the C# delegate type it **automatically generates** a sealed class deriving from System.MulticastDelegate.

```
sealed class Add : System.MulticastDelegate
{
   public int Invoke(int x, int y);
   public IAsyncResult BeginInvoke(int x, int y, AsyncCallback cb, object state);
   public int EndInvoke(IAsyncResult result);
}
```

[QuiteCode](http://quitecode.com/advance/delegates.htm)

Answer (score 0):

`Delegates` are special types, that sentence probably means that you can't manually inherit from `Delegate` or `MulticastDelegate` class because they are special classes.So the `C#` compiler creates types that inherits from `MulticastDelegate` and declares those methods according to the signature of `delegate` type automatically.

Or possibly, it means that since the delegate type changes the signatures of those methods, they are not inherited but instead they created by compiler *from scratch*,  depending on the type of the delegate.(after re-reading, this makes more sense).